# How many combinations of $\left ( a,b,c \right )$ are there that makes $a^\left ({b^{c}} \right )$ a prime number

Tags: prime-numbers

$a,b$ and $c$ are all **digits**. How many different combinations of $\left ( a,b,c \right )$ are there that makes $a^\left ({b^{c}}  \right )$ a prime number?

Obviously $a$ has to be $2,3,5$ or $7$ and $b^{c}$ must equal $1$. When $b=1$, $c$ can be anything.

So $\left (4\cdot 1\cdot 10  \right ) = 40$ is my answer but the answer key says it is 72.

Comment: Please, if the answer is sitting in front of my eyes, feel free to *lead* me rather than giving me the answer right up. I tried on my own and failed.

Comment: Well, $a$ prime, $b=1$, $c$ could be anything.

Comment: $b$ cannot be zero, as $2^{(0^3)}=2^0=1,$ which is not prime.  That still doesn't match your answer key, but I would answer $40$

Comment: @RossMillikan is right, except that if both $b$ **and** $c$ are $0$ it is allowable.  $0^0=1$.

Comment: @Wildcard:  some define $0^0=1,$ some say it is undefined.  We have questions on that on this site.

Comment: You guy are correct. Sorry for my mistake. Got upset so much that my mind is actually inaccurate. Edited the question to correct that.

Comment: Still, the closest we get is $40$. Should I assume the answer key is wrong?

Comment: @ZacharySelk It asks the total number of combinations that results in a prime number.

Comment: Working the answer key's answer in reverse, let's allow that $a$ must be one of $2, 3, 5, 7$.  This means that the possibilities for $b$ and $c$ **according to your answer key** must be accounted for in $72/4=18$ possibilities.  Not only is this incorrect, I can't even *guess* at what errors they are making in counting to wind up with this answer.  (I'm usually pretty good at making such guesses.)

Comment: @Wildcard $18$ is indeed correct.

Comment: @ZacharySelk, haha, right you are.  I almost had it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we need $a$ to be prime, so $a=2,3,5,7$. We also need $b^c=1$. So either $b=1$ or $c=0$. If $b=1$ then $c$ can be $0,...,9$ so we have $10$ options. If $c=0$ then $b$ can be $1,...,9$ (as $0^0$ is undefined). However we double counted $1^0$, so we have $10+8=18$ ways for $b^c=1$.

So then pick an $a$ to get $4\cdot 18=72$ ways.